# How to access passed value in the Statefulwidget?

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I am passing an `String` from another `StatefulWidget` to the below `CardItem StatefulWidget` and then from here the `String` is passed to the `_CardItemState` as shown in the code below.
But how this `String` passed should be accessed from `_CardItemState(String itemTitle);`

```
class CardItem extends StatefulWidget {


  String itemTitle;
  CardItem({@required this.itemTitle});
  @override
  _CardItemState createState() => _CardItemState(itemTitle);
}

class _CardItemState extends State<CardItem> {

  _CardItemState(String itemTitle);


 void initState(){
   print("INiatialize");
   print("itemTitle is  "  +  );
 }

}
```

Comment: remove `CardItemState(String itemTitle);` constructor and access any `Widget`'s fields by using `State.widget` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this is to use

> widget.fieldName

```
    class CardItem extends StatefulWidget {
      String itemTitle;
      CardItem({@required this.itemTitle});
      @override
      _CardItemState createState() => _CardItemState(itemTitle:itemTitle);
    }
    
    class _CardItemState extends State<CardItem> {
    
      String myItemTitle;
      @override
      void initState(){

       super.initState();
       myItemTitle=widget.itemTitle;
       print("INiatialize");
       print("itemTitle is  $myItemTitle";
     
     }
    
    }
```

otherway round to this problem is to pass data in constructor as shown below, but the above method is recommended to be followed.

```
 class CardItem extends StatefulWidget {


  String itemTitle;
  CardItem({@required this.itemTitle});
  @override
  _CardItemState createState() => _CardItemState(itemTitle:itemTitle);
}

class _CardItemState extends State<CardItem> {

   String itemTitle;
  _CardItemState({this.itemTitle});


 void initState(){
   print("INiatialize");
   print("itemTitle is  $itemTitle";
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access it via `widget.itemTitle`. For your case you can call it like this:

```
 printItem(){
  print("itemTitle is ${widget.itemTitle}");
 }

 void initState(){
   printItem();
   super.initState();
 }
```

You also don't need to pass the string in your state constructor. Remove this:

```
_CardItemState(String itemTitle);
```

Comment: @Mark Davids Does it show an error? I think it works inside initState.

Comment: You should mention that there is no need to pass the String in the State contructor

Comment: @AugustinR Thanks for that. I updated my answer. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

easy! grab it using

> widget.itemTitle

```
class CardItem extends StatefulWidget {


  String itemTitle;
  CardItem({@required this.itemTitle});
  @override
  _CardItemState createState() => _CardItemState(itemTitle);
}

class _CardItemState extends State<CardItem> {
  String itemTitle; // - 1
  _CardItemState(this.itemTitle); // - 2


 void initState(){
   itemTitle = widget.itemTitle;  // - 3;
   print("INiatialize");
   print("itemTitle is  "  + itemTitle ); // - 4
   print("itemTitle is  "  + widget.itemTitle ); // same as - 4 
 }

}
```